# Scrolling in html table

Tags: jquery, scroll, html-table

I have a table

```
<table>
  <tr><td>00:00</td><td>Text1</td></td>
  .
  .
  <tr><td>23:00</td><td>Text23</td></td>
</table>
```

I want to hide `<tr>` tags from 00:00 to 07:00, and when page load my table shows from 08:00  But I want to have a possibility scrolling to first element in table. I tried to use different plugins for jQuery, but it was unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried ? What about coding your own plugin ? How do you expect to visually toggle rows ?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the table in a scrollable div... http://jsfiddle.net/qm7Vx/

Just change the height to what you want. You can also add the width property to your style attribute if you want to scroll horizontally also.

```
<div style="height:200px;overflow:auto;" id="tableScroller">
  <table>
  <tr><td>00:00</td><td>Text1</td></td>
  .
  .
  <tr><td>23:00</td><td>Text23</td></td>
  </table>
</div>
```

This will show the FIRST N rows depending on the height with the ability to scroll down. It sounds like you want to show the LAST N Rows with the ability to scroll up. Might I suggest reversing the order the rows are displayed, showing the latest first?

**Otherwise** you can use jQuery to set the scroll position of your div.

```
$('#tableScroller').scrollTop( $('#tableScroller table').height() );
```

Answer (score 1):

No plugin needed, just put the table inside a scrollable container and use something like the following set of code:

HTML:

```
<div id="tableContainer" style="height:200px; overflow:auto;">
    <table>
        <tr><td>00:00</td><td>Text1</td></td>
        .
        .
        <tr><td>23:00</td><td>Text23</td></td>
    </table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var howMuchToScroll = $('div#tableContainer table td:contains("08:00")').offset().top - $('div#tableContainer table').offset().top;
    $('div#tableContainer').scrollTop(howMuchToScroll);
});
```

This script will allow you to automatically scroll to any given time (in this case `08:00`) and will hide any items above assuming it can scroll down further. It will also allow you to hide later times if you choose the right height.

See a working demo at the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/wW7Y2/).

Comment: Also, try max-height:200px if you want the div to grow with the table up to a certain point.